# Regex to Match string after time

Tags: regex, splunk

Struggling with extracting Hostnames from log messages , it mucks up when the date changes from 2 digit to single digit , like from 31st Oct to 1 nov , the extraction of the keyword start failing ...here are few logs for which i need to extract the hostnames

- Nov  1 00:00:21 akdcs20.ftc.abcd-ipsn AKDCS20 fpc0
  LBCM-L2,brcm_port_learning_config(),1258:(brcm_port_learning_config:1258) Setting L2 learning unit:0,port_num:44, learn_flg 5
- Nov  1 01:27:16 spnztpm01.abcd-ipsn 553177: LC/0/0/CPU0:Nov  1
  01:27:16.040 : ifmgr[200]: %PKT_INFRA-LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN : Line
  protocol on Interface TenGigE0/0/0/1.172153, changed state to Up
- Oct 31 23:59:56 akdcs19.ftc.abcd-ipsn AKDCS19 ufdd[1679]:
  ufd_group_config_if_lookup ifname ae4

For all three above lines i want to extract

- akdcs19.ftc.abcd-ipsn
- spnztpm01.abcd-ipsn
- akdcs20.ftc.abcd-ipsn

current regex i am using is 
`^(?:[^ \n]* ){4}(?P<devicename1>[^ ]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\s\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\s+(?P<devicename1>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCwkvP/1).

Or, a more explicit pattern:

```
^\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\s+(?P<devicename1>\S+)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCwkvP/2).

**Details**

- `^\w+\s+\d+\s+` - start of string, 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespaces, 1+ digits, 1+ whitespaces (that is, to make sure we are getting to the right time-like substring)
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?::\d{2}){2}` - two sequences of `:` and two digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<devicename1>\S+)` - Group "devicename1": one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the date part will always be the month with 3 char, the day with 1-2 and the time with HH:MM:ss:

```
^(?:\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s)(?P<devicename1>[^ ]+)
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/YSYBYQ/1)